# Small square on upper left corner of window when panel is switched wxpython

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am facing a problem with wx.panels.
In my project have created file with wx.frame inherited in a class in a file and other two files have wx.panels inherited.
I am trying to hide/destroy panel1 and call panel2 but somehow its not working. A small square icon with panel background color appears on switch.
I refered [this topic][1] on stackoverflow but I found if I do not use sizers the code does not work (when split in different files.)
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58794753/wxpython-panel-is-cropped-with-only-a-small-box-shown-at-the-top-left-hand-corne

main.py

```
import sys
import wx
from test1 import panel1
from test2 import panel2

class main(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.panel = panel1(parent=self)
        self.Show()
        # display=wx.Display()
        # size = display.GetGeometry().GetSize()
        # print(size)

    def update_window(self):
        self.panel2=panel2(self,wx.ID_ANY)
        self.panel2.Show()
        self.panel.Hide()
        self.Refresh()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(__file__)
    app = wx.App()  # Create a new app, don't redirect stdout/stderr to a window.
    frame = main(None, wx.ID_ANY, "Hello World",size=(1024,700)) # A Frame is a top-level window.
    frame.Show(True)     # Show the frame.
    app.MainLoop()
```

test1.py

```
import wx
from view.panel import custom_panel
from test2 import panel2

class panel1(custom_panel):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent=parent
        self.btn1 = wx.Button(self,wx.ID_ANY,"button1",pos=(100,50),size=(300,50))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.On_btn1_clicked, self.btn1)


    def On_btn1_clicked(self, event):
        self.parent.update_window()
```

test2.py

```
import wx
from view.panel import custom_panel

class panel2(custom_panel):
    def __init__(self,parent=None,id=None,size=(1024,700)):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent=parent
        self.btn2 = wx.Button(self,wx.ID_ANY,"button2",pos=(300,50),size=(300,50))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.On_btn2_clicked, self.btn2)


    def On_btn2_clicked(self, event):
        self.parent.update_window()
```

custom_panel.py

```
import wx

class custom_panel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("#000000")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
```

Comment: Please share a code you are using to deal with your issue.

Comment: Please have a look at the thread now @AlexK.

Answer (score 0):

@PavanHebli,

I strongly suggest you learn sizers and how to use them.

While you solution definitely work, it is very bad solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I also agree on using sizers.

**BUT:** I also had to problem a very long time and did not know the solution. The sizers did not work (as I expected)

For me, the problem was, that the panel had no (or the incorrect size).
The solution was eiter:

`panel.Fit()`
or
`panel.SetSize(x,y)`

Answer (score -2):

Solved!
while creating the second panel I was passing only the parent and I guess wx.DefaultSize was not working for the second panel unlike the first panel.
what I had to do was just pass **size=(1024,700) in the test2.py file's **init** method** like this:

```
super().__init__(parent,id=id,size=(1024,700))
```

That's it.

Comment: Don’t do this. This is so very bad at any level I can think of. Just use a sizer and Hide() and Show() the panels as required. And for heaven’s sake do not ever ever ever pass explicit sizes like that, like never ever **ever**.